# Docker - mount cifs volume without subfolder

Tags: docker, docker-volume, samba, smb, cifs

Is it possible mount CIFS volume root folder?

Something like this:

```
my-storage:
        driver: local
        driver_opts:
            type: cifs
            device: '//IP-address'
            o: 'file_mode=0600,dir_mode=0755,username=admin,password=pass'
```

I only managed to mount a subfolder like //IP-address/some-dir

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this will work this way, the listing of shares on a server is not the same as listing of objects in a share. These are different protocols. Thus it must be handled another way by the client. What you call root folder is not a folder but the listing of shares on the host, it could be a printer as well.
Example Share Listing: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-rap/48dd86d2-4092-49a4-9024-308f0ed77520 
Example Directory Listing: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-smb2/10906442-294c-46d3-8515-c277efe1f752 
As you can see, the first is called MS-RAP, the second MS-SMB.
An overview of how protocols interact, see here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-smb/592d0cbe-41d0-4b8e-8bb9-a60edd85e5e8